# Is there a maintained version of WMD

Tags: markdown, wmd, pagedown

Is there a version of WMD: The Wysiwym Markdown Editor, available which has been maintained the last years? If found a gazillion different version like [this](https://github.com/openlibrary/wmd) one but all haven't been updated since a few years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) is our fork of WMD that we use here on Stack Overflow. You tagged your question [pagedown](/questions/tagged/pagedown), so I assume you found it. Not sure what makes you think it's not maintained; any bugfix we make to the Stack Overflow version also ends up there – and usually faster than it's rolled out to Stack Overflow.